# Android Toolbar moves up when keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-toolbar, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat

I'm creating a chat based UI screen where I have toolbar and recyclerview for chat messages, and reply msg layout.

Whenever edittext get focus It moves up the toolbar. Instead I would like to resize the recyclerview.

some of the **stackoverflow answers** suggest to place a **empty scrollview** below the **toolbar**, but It didn't work.

```
        <activity
            android:name=".PostMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_post_message"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            >
        </activity>
```

I am setting the `windowSoftInputMode` to `stateVisible|adjustPan` in the manifest file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.pasonet.yokibu.PostMessageActivity"
>
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_home"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ScrollView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_home"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/add_post_layout"
    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/post_msg_recyclerview"
        >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/add_post_layout"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="0pt"
   >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@color/trasnperant"
        android:hint="Type your message"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_36dp"
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:background="@drawable/abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape"
        android:onClick="addPost"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` in `styles.xml`

To enable `adjustResize` add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your activity's parent layout

Comment: does not work for me, In general when you have a bg inside this screen is hard to manage, just adjustPan not rezize your background. With Background and status bar fixed , this does not work. 

Im searching here to fix this , but im not found anything yet.

Comment: After adding this code my screen is adjusted perfectly, but i'm getting a white patch i.e something like margin bottom in my toobar.. How to avoid that.?

Comment: This code works. but below and above toolbar it shows white statusbar

Comment: This doesn't work, I'm using `AppBarLayout`, `ToolBar` and `NestedScrollView`

Comment: What is an "activity's parent"? Did you mean the activity root layout? The 's means is possessive in English so I didn't know an activity had a parent that wasn't part of the Android system.

Comment: using adjustResize, u will lose animation when keyboard show, that's bad choice

Answer (score 14):

Or add this line in manifest. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Comment: This is bad solution because using `adjustResize` your page with `textedit` will not scroll to the element

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want your `Toolbar` to be pushed up, you shouldn't be using `adjustPan`. Using `adjustResize` without any other things (without adding any additional `Views`) should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I've tried the `adjustResize` also it didn't work. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Therefore there must be some issue with your layout. And to be honest I don't really get the layout file you provided. Why is your `RecyclerView` wrapped inside a `LinearLayout`? Also, since you've decided to use a `RelativeLayout` as a root, try setting `android:layout_alignParentTop="true` for your `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, my default application was using Coordinator Layout for the root element. Even doing what was described above wasn't solving my problem. 
Then I did the following:

1. Changed the root layout from Coordinator Layout to RelativeLayout
2. Included `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root layout
3. Included `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"` to the activity manifest tag.

Answer (score 5):

You should add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in your toolbar's root layout. If you add it in your activity's parent layout, a strange line (with status bar height) will appear above your toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Here is the solution for this fix

- `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in Manifest File
- Make a class "CommentKeyBoardFix.Java" and copy and paste the below code.

  ```
  public class CommentKeyBoardFix
  {
  private View mChildOfContent;
  private int usableHeightPrevious;
  private FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutParams;
  private Rect contentAreaOfWindowBounds = new Rect();

  public CommentKeyBoardFix(Activity activity)
  {
      FrameLayout content = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
      mChildOfContent = content.getChildAt(0);
      mChildOfContent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this::possiblyResizeChildOfContent);
      frameLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mChildOfContent.getLayoutParams();
  }

  private void possiblyResizeChildOfContent()
  {
      int usableHeightNow = computeUsableHeight();
      if (usableHeightNow != usableHeightPrevious)
      {
          int heightDifference = 0;
          if (heightDifference > (usableHeightNow /4))
          {
              // keyboard probably just became visible
              frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightNow - heightDifference;
          }
          else
          {
              // keyboard probably just became hidden
              frameLayoutParams.height = usableHeightNow;
          }
          mChildOfContent.layout(contentAreaOfWindowBounds.left, contentAreaOfWindowBounds.top, contentAreaOfWindowBounds.right, contentAreaOfWindowBounds.bottom);
          mChildOfContent.requestLayout();
          usableHeightPrevious = usableHeightNow;
      }
  }

  private int computeUsableHeight()
  {
      mChildOfContent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(contentAreaOfWindowBounds);
      return contentAreaOfWindowBounds.height();
  }
  }
  ```

  And then call this class in your Activity or Fragment; for Kotlin:

  ```
  setContentView(R.layout.your_comments_layout)
  CommentKeyBoardFix(this)
  ```

  or for Java:

  ```
  new CommentKeyBoardFix(this)
  ```

Comment: Screen flickers when i use this fix.

Answer (score 2):

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_home"
    android:elevation="5dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check WindowsSoftInputMode in Android Manifest
try to set AdjustResize or AdjsutPan

Answer (score 1):

1. Include `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root in xml file of the activty.
2. Include `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` to the activity manifest tag.

These two steps solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in your manifest.xml in activity tag.

Answer (score 0):

Using  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` on the activity in the manifest worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways to keep the toolbar fixed , while not resizing or compressing the layout by android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" , that is not a proper .

That is only possible by Coordinator layout ,

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:ripple="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:background="#fff"
           ripple:contentInsetStart="0dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/coordinate_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:marginTop="56dp">
</ScrollView>
```

Keep the structure as

```
 Coordinator layout
  |-->Toolbar    (android:id="@+id/toolbar")
  |-->ScrollView (android:layout_below="@id/toolbar")
   |-->Child
   |-->Child
   |-->Child
```

Answer (score 0):

If **NOTHING** work, be aware that libraries can manipulate soft input, for example `com.arlib.floatingsearchview`.

[image]

What happen is, for example you have list view with search view, when you show the fragment with `floatingsearchview` its set soft input to `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN`(you may not care about it in fragment with list view), but if the next fragment will be item details with many edit texts it will push the toolbar up.

In my case I cannot replace this library so i set `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE` in the base fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to make `windowFullscreen` to false in `styles.xml` in combination with [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33062438/6478047)  to make it work

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this

> fitsSystemWindows

inside scrollview and it solved:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/rootScrollview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

I initially had `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` on the AndroidManifest for activity with toolbar, a chat message recycler view and input on the bottom.

This was getting desired result of recycler view going up on input view receiving focus and keyboard opening up but the Toolbar was hiding

After trying out a bunch of solutions, what worked for me was:
**No `windowSoftInputMode` at all**

and

`app:stackFromEnd="true"` on the recycler view

Answer (score -1):

I use a `CoordinatorLayout` as root Layout for the toolbar. I had the same problem but solved it by setting the toolbar to:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
```

instead of:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

and adding:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

in the activity in the manifest.