# Android actionbar/toolbar disappears after writing to edittext

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-toolbar

I'm stuck at this. I have an app where I have several pages made as fragments. Every page is good except the last one where when I tap on editText, action bar disappears and when I unfocus it, action bar didn't show up back.

I've tried changing appTheme to all kind of themes but they didn't change anything, most of them forced app to crash.

Here is my layout of that page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView27"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView28"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView29"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.64"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView30"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView31"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView32"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView33"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.78" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView34"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.91" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView25"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/houroff"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView27"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.03" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/minuteOffsetText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/minuteoff"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView28"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.16" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vinText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/vinen"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView29"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.29" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/defaultText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/defen"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView30"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.40" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vhconst"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/vehicle_const"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView31"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/output"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView32"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.645" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tripText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="TRIP\nRESET"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView33"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.76" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/odoText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/odores"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView34"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.895" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/minOffSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:checked="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.155" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/vinSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:checked="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.285" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/defaultSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:checked="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.40" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/tripResetSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:checked="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.76" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/odoResetSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:checked="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.895" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/eVehConstSet"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="00000"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vhconst"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/eOutShaftSet"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="0.000"
    android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/shft"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.645" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hourOffset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView25"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/minOffset"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView25"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13999999" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vinResetText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="VIN RESET"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vinReset"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.29" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/vinReset"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/vinResS"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.11"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/vinResetText"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.27999997" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pulsem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fraction"
    android:text="@string/vehicle_const_pm"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/eVehConstSet"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.51" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pulser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fraction"
    android:text="@string/output_const"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/eOutShaftSet"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.64" />
```

and this is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
public static float density = 0;
public static float dpHeight = 0;
public static float dpWidth = 0;

public String macAdress;
public UUID myUUID;
public static int index = 1;
public boolean ConnectSuccess = false;
private ProgressDialog progress;
public BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
public BluetoothAdapter mBluetooth = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().show();
            TextView t = findViewById(R.id.title);
            switch (position+1){
                case 1:
                    t.setText("Virtual TG Setup");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    t.setText("Virtual TG Live");

                    break;
                case 3:
                    t.setText("Virtual TG Config");

                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().show();
        }
    });
    Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    d.getMetrics(outMetrics);
    density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
    dpWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
    System.out.println(density);
    System.out.println(dpHeight);
    System.out.println(dpWidth);
    System.out.println(outMetrics.heightPixels);
    System.out.println(outMetrics.widthPixels);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    macAdress = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA");
    if (macAdress != null) {
        new BTConnect().execute();
    } else {

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: OP , possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32649710/4936904

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `windowSoftInputMode` in manifest. Choose which is most suitable for you.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work. Toolbar never returns.